# How to set up a basic symfony 4 background task?

Tags: php, symfony4, background-task

I am trying to set up a very basic hello background task in my Symfony 4 project. I have tried using `mmucklo/DtcQueueBundle` having a Hello class as

```
<?php


namespace App\Worker;


class Hello extends \Dtc\QueueBundle\Model\Worker
{
    public function run(string $name = null, int $times = 1, bool $askHowTheyAre = false): int
    {
        if (null === $name) {
            $name = '';
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < $times; $i++) {
            $message = sprintf(
                'Hello %s',
                $name
            );
            if ($askHowTheyAre) {
                $message .= ', How are you?';
            }
            print($message.PHP_EOL);
        }
        return self::RESULT_SUCCESS;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'hello';
    }
}
```

as suggested in the documentation. But when I run

```
bin/console dtc:queue:create_job -j hello run '[ "Matthew" ]'
```

I get the following error

> In WorkerCompilerPass.php line 120:
>   Class  does not exist

Has anyone worked with DtcQueueBundle before or has another background task method to suggest for Symfony 4?

Comment: Did you create a service for your worker? like [here](https://github.com/mmucklo/DtcQueueBundle#yaml)

Comment: https://github.com/php-amqplib/RabbitMqBundle
i've tried this bundle it works